# Pronom de reprise pour ceci dans une question avec des verbes modaux

Tags: pronoms, questions, inversion, pronom-de-reprise

Comment doit-on utiliser le pronom de reprise dans une question où il y a une inversion et le pronom ceci ?

Par exemple, la question  « *Que ceci veut dire ?* » peut être réécrite de cette façon: « *Qu'est-ce que ceci veut dire ?* ». Mais avec une inversion de sujet, comment doit-on l'écrire ?

1. Que ceci veut-il dire ?
2. Que veut dire ceci ?

J'ai posé cette question à un français et il m'a dit qu'il utiliserait plutôt la deuxième option et qu'il n'est même pas sûr que la première soit correcte. (Mais il a avoué que c'est peut-être parce qu'il s'agit d'un type de construction utilisée très rarement, donc il n'y serait pas habitué).

Des phrases similaires avec les verbes "pouvoir" et "devoir" semblent aussi étranges... Par exemple, comment écrirait-on la phrase suivante en utilisant l'inversion de sujet et le pronom de reprise ?

« Que ceci peut signifier ? »

Comment: je n'ai jamais rencontré la première forme, elle ne me semble pas correcte non plus

Comment: « **Que cela veut-il dire**, Monsieur ? est-ce qu'il est plus poli, plus affable qu'un autre ? » Montesquieu, *Lettres Persanes*.

Comment: Bonne référence. Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il me semble raisonnable de penser que même un francophone natif pourrait avoir du mal à répondre à cette question à brûle-pourpoint, ayant moi-même éprouvé le sentiment d’incertitude de votre contact par rapport à ***« Que ceci veut-il dire ? »***. La tournure sonne étrange aujourd’hui. On ne saurait la dire froncièrement incorrecte, mais elle n’est pas courante, plutôt même inusitée.

*Le bon usage* de Grevisse m’a semblé une source de réponse plausible, et après quelque recherche, j’y ai trouvé un article dédié *(14<sup>e</sup> édition, §396 b 3°) :*

> Plus d’un auteur, continuant un usage ancien, met le sujet immédiatement après *que*, en reprenant ce sujet par un pronom personnel :
>
> *Que **tout cela** serait-**il** devenu si mon absence se fût prolongée ?* (J.-J. AMPÈRE, lettre, dans A.-M. et J.-J. Ampère, *Correspondance et souvenirs,* t. I, p. 301.) — *Que **Pellerin** devrait-**il** dire à Ermance ?* (LA VARENDE, *Cœur pensif...*, p. 209) — *Que **cela** change-t-**il** ?* (VIALAR, *Petit garçon de l’ascenseur*, p. 170)

Ce dernier exemple suit très exactement la structure de *« Que ceci veut-il dire ? »*, qui semble donc historiquement avérée, mais reflet d’un usage ancien qui ne subsiste que marginalement aujourd’hui.

Par contre, *« Que ceci veut dire ? »* ou *« Que ceci peut signifier ? »* ne reprennent pas le sujet par un pronom personnel et ne tombent par conséquent pas sous cet article. La tournure sonne d’ailleurs très faux dans mon esprit de francophone natif. À éviter...

La tournure ***« Que veut dire ceci ? »*** est quant à elle bien plus commune et ne me semble pas controversée ou incertaine. Elle est utilisée et correcte.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Si j'ai bien compris [cet article de l'Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/reprise-pronominale-du-sujet-exprime-dans-linterrogation-combien-dauteurs-sont-ils-selectionnes), dans les interrogations partielles (celles avec "que", "pourquoi", "combien", etc), ces reprises pronominales sont correctes, mais on fait mieux de les éviter. Êtes-vous d'accord avec mon interprétation ?

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Je crois que c’est en effet ce que l’Académie semble indiquer. Elle est une source fiable d’informations linguistiques, qui penche plutôt vers le purisme, et n’est pas ma préférée, mais quiconque suit ses recommendations ne saurait être vraiment en erreur. Que de grands auteurs actuels ou récents **perpétuent** un usage ancien me semble aussi avoir un poids...

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Je note à l'instant que l'article parle des interrogations **partielles**, ce que vous avez mentionné d'ailleurs, mais qui ne représente pas le cas de votre question, ou celui de l'article du *Bon usage* cité dans ma réponse.

Comment: Voulez-vous dire que «Que veut dire ceci ?» et «Que cela change-t-il ?» ne sont pas des interrogations partielles ? Je ne comprends pas ...

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Je voulais dire que l'article de l'Académie mentionne une information liée à une interrogation partielle. *«Que veut dire ceci?»* ou *«Que ceci veut-il dire?»* sont de pleines et entières interrogations. On n'affirme pas à moitié en demandant, comme dans *«Combien d'enfants veulent-ils manger?»*, dans laquelle on sous-entend d'ores et déjà que beaucoup d'enfant veulent manger, mais qu'on ne connaît pas l'ordre exact de leur nombre.

Comment: D'accord... Je pensais que la définition d'interrogation partielle était syntaxique et que l'on ne considérait pas la sémantique dans ce cas. C'est-à-dire, lorsqu'il y avait un pronom ou un déterminant interrogatif (que, lequel, pourquoi, etc), je dirais qu'il s'agit d'une interrogation partielle. Enfin, cela n'est pas très important par l'instant ...  Conclusion: pour dire « *ça veut dire quoi ?* » de façon formelle, je vais plutôt utiliser « *Que veut dire ceci/cela ?* ». Merci beaucoup une autre fois !

Comment: Oh, excusez-moi, juste une dernière question : Pensez-vous que les reprises pronominales sonnent moins étrange dans les interrogation totales ? Par exemple, « Paul veut-il du café ? » ou « Le bébé sait-il déjà marcher ? ».

Comment: *«Paul veut-il du café?»* et *«Bébé sait-il déja marcher?»* me semble très acceptables et naturelles.

Answer (score 2):

Comme l'indique le commentaire de Flying_whale, la première phrase n'est pas correcte, tandis que la seconde l'est.

Le problème de compréhension provient à mon avis de la prémisse de la question, car la phrase « *Que ceci veut dire ?* » qui semble être le point de départ du raisonnement, n'est pas correcte. Il faut employer la seconde proposition « *Que veut dire ceci ?* ». Sinon, l'autre tournure proposée, « *Qu'est-ce que ceci veut dire ?* » est également correcte.

De même, « *Que ceci peut signifier ?* » est incorrect, la forme à utiliser serait « *Que peut signifier ceci ?* » ou « Qu'est-ce que ceci peut signifier ? ».

Comment: Mais est-ce que c'est un problème avec le mot "ceci" ? Par exemple, la phrase « Que Paul veut-il dire ?» est-elle correcte ? Merci beaucoup.

Comment: La phrase « Que Paul veut-il dire ?» ne me semble pas correcte non plus. « Que veut dire Paul ?» ou bien, si on a déjà fait référence à Paul avant, « Que veut-il dire ?» sont correctes. "Il" fait référence à Paul, il n'est pas utile de l'employer si "Paul" est déjà dans la phrase. C'est peut être utilisé dans certains cas pour insister sur le sujet mais je ne l'ai jamais vu et ne parviens pas à trouver d'exemple sur internet

Comment: @Batman «Mais que diable Batman voulait-il donc dire par là ?» ou «Mais que diable voulait donc dire Batman par là ?»... Les deux me semblent correctes. Je trouve même la première plus chantante. 
Le problème avec *ceci*, c'est qu'il suppose qu'on a déjà parlé de quelque chose auquel on se réfère. La phrase toute seule, elle est grave bizarre. Mon humble avis.