# « Où cela en est-il? » vs. « Où cela en est? »

Tags: pronoms, questions, constructions

Je souhaiterais savoir quelle est la bonne construction entre « Où cela en est-il? » et « Où cela en est? », et pourquoi?

En tant que locuteur natif, il me semble que c'est « Où cela en est-il? », pourtant je n'arrive pas à me l'expliquer. En effet on dit « Où en es-tu? », on devrait donc dire "Où en est-ce?", pourtant ça sonne faux à mon oreille. Cependant dans « "Où cela en est-il?" », le « il » me semble redondant. L'on souhaite savoir où en est « cela », pourquoi donc rajouter « il ». Je me demande donc quelle règle grammaticale justifie cette construction.

Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a plein de manières de poser la question:

> Où en est-ce ?
>
> Où en est cela ?
>
> Où cela en est-il ?
>
> Où ça en est ?
>
> Ça en est où ?

La première et la deuxième sont en fait très similaires, le "ce" étant la forme courte de "cela"

L'ajout du "-il" lors du passage au troisième exemple vient du fait que si le sujet est un nom et qu'on le place devant le verbe (alors que la forme interrogative voudrait qu'il soit derrière), on doit ajouter le pronom approprié derrière le verbe. Alors certes "cela" n'est pas un nom, mais il vient simplement en remplacer un qui aura été mentionné avant dans le contexte.

La quatrième et cinquième formes qui sont souvent utilisées de nos jours en langage courant sont simplement calqués sur la forme affirmative à laquelle on ajoute un point d'interrogation (et à l'oral l'intonation sera différente entre "Tu me diras où ca en est." et "Tu me diras où ca en est ?")

Selon moi "Où cela en est ?" est tout aussi acceptable que les autres exemples sur le plan grammatical, mais je le trouve bien moins idiomatique. Il y a de fortes chances que si l'on est dans un registre familier (on n'utilise pas la forme interrogative inversée) on emploiera plutôt "ça" que "cela"

Si on remplace "cela" par "le projet" par exemple, tout devient beaucoup plus clair je trouve...

Note: il y a évidemment d'autres moyens de poser la même question mais on s'éloigne alors de l'idée de la question d'origine

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette réponse. 1) « L'ajout du "-il" lors du passage au troisième exemple vient du fait que si le sujet est un nom et qu'on le place devant le verbe (alors que la forme interrogative voudrait qu'il soit derrière), on doit ajouter le pronom approprié derrière le verbe. »
Parfait c'est exactement la règle que je cherchais. Au passage « cela » n'est pas un nom, mais il me semble qu'il en a la fct. 2) En fait les constructions 4 et 5 sont grammaticalement fausses je pense, mais utilisées de manière courante à l'oral. 3) Quels sont ces autres moyens que vous décrivez à la fin?

Comment: 4) « cela » est moins idiomatique, mais « ça » est plus familier, même si presque tout le temps utilisé à l'oral. « cela » me paraît donc être un meilleur candidat en bon français. Ou alors « ce » avec la contraction « c' ».

Answer (score 1):

La première est conforme à l'usage, même si l'Académie française [n'aime pas trop](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/reprise-pronominale-du-sujet-exprime-dans-linterrogation-combien-dauteurs-sont-ils-selectionnes), le *il* étant un pronom de reprise déjà souvent évoqué ici<sup>1</sup>.

> Où cela en est-il ?

La deuxième est aussi correcte :

> Où cela en est ?

mais on entendra plus souvent:

> Où ça en est ?

ainsi que d'autres variantes telles que :

> Où est-ce que ça en est ?
>
> Ça en est où ?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>-
[Doit-on dire « Quelle confiture est la meilleure ? » ou « Quelle confiture est-elle la meilleure ? »?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/993/doit-on-dire-quelle-confiture-est-la-meilleure-ou-quelle-confiture-est-e)

- [« Comment devient » ou « comment devient-il » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5888/comment-devient-ou-comment-devient-il)

- [« Combien de Français sont-ils concernés par » est-il correct ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2724/combien-de-fran%c3%a7ais-sont-ils-concern%c3%a9s-par-est-il-correct/2731#2731)

- [Pronom de reprise pour ceci dans une question avec des verbes modaux](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31658/pronom-de-reprise-pour-ceci-dans-une-question-avec-des-verbes-modaux)</sub>

Comment: Et voilà, comme d'habitude une super réponse avec les termes techniques (pronom de reprise) et les références qui vont bien. J'adore :-)

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette réponse. En fait j'ai utilisé « cela », mais j'aurais pu utiliser « ça » qui est une forme courte et plus familière de « cela » il me semble.

Comment: Oui, je dirais même plutôt que *cela* est une forme qui n'est plus utilisée aujourd'hui dans le registre du français parlé, ce qui explique qu'il peut sonner faux, ou maniéré  comme dans la réplique culte: *c'est cela, oui*

Comment: Une expression quand-même où "cela" peut difficilement être remplacé par "ça": "Ceci explique cela".

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, c'est vrai. C'est une expression figée, *ça explique ça* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre. Je ne suis pas d'accord concernant « cela », il est plus formel certes, mais de là à dire qu'il n'est plus utilisé ou qu'il peut sonner faux, cela ;) est peut-être un peu trop exagéré. Par contre, oui il sonne maniéré, mais de toute façon le français est une langue maniérée, voire même grandiloquente lorsqu'elle est bien parlée, avec une tendance à l'emphase et à la précision, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @moth Tu as mal lu ma réponse. Je n'ai pas dit qu'il n'était plus utilisé, seulement qu'il avait disparu du registre du français parlé. On peut bien sûr utiliser un registre soutenu et dire *cela* ou *n'est-ce pas*, mais ce n'est pas courant.